# Appium Sauce Lab Tapping on iOS Simulator Not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios, saucelabs

Currently I am loading an image in a webview. I want to be able to tap the image, but when I do so it doesn't seem to actually register in Sauce Lab.

```html
 IOSDriver driver = (IOSDriver) contextObj.getValue("driver");
        final JSONObject params = new JSONObject(parameters);
        Set<String> contextHandles = driver.getContextHandles();
        ArrayList<String> contexts = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String context : contextHandles) {
            contexts.add(context);
            System.out.println("Available Context: " + context);
        }
        String newContext = contexts.get(1);
        driver.context(newContext);
        seleniumSteps.driverWait("15000");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        WebElement firstDivElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div)[1]"));
        Point imageLocation = firstDivElement.getLocation();
        Dimension size = firstDivElement.getSize();
        int elementCenterX = imageLocation.getX() + Math.round(size.getWidth() / 2);
        int elementCenterY = imageLocation.getY() + Math.round(size.getHeight() / 2);
        System.out.println("X Coordinate: " + elementCenterX);
        System.out.println("Y Coordinate: " + elementCenterY);
        driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
        seleniumSteps.driverWait("5000");
        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence tap = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), elementCenterX, elementCenterY));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        driver.perform(Arrays.asList(tap));
```

I've tried to use the deprecated touchActions class and get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I found that you need to enable a capability on startup to allow taps to happen.

Here is what worked for me:

```html
caps.setCapability("nativeWebTap",true);
```